# Laravel : Added a package that can get address from ip address but showing error stevebauman/location

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package

I have updated the composer and run the php artisan publish commands as per their advice in this link

https://github.com/stevebauman/location

**This is the program i run**

*Getting a user location (automatic IP detection):*

$location = Location::get();
Getting a user location with a specific IP:

Location::get('192.168.1.1');

[image: This is the error when i run the program]

Comment: Set localhost_testing variable in the packages config file  to be false.

Comment: I did that , but still showing same error , what should be the header for this class , Now i have given use Stevebauman\Location\Objects\Location;

Comment: Run composer dump-autoload
composer clear-cache
composer update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to run `composer install` or `composer update`. The error shown that the library is not exist in your project.